# How can I solve/suppress IntelliJ warning that mock class is not declared in any Angular module?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an Angular 8 app where I am trying to mock some sub components.

The mocking itself is fine. However, for the sake of organization and reusability, I want to move the mocks out of the *.spec* file and into its own mock directory as shown below:

```
myApp
|-- src
    |-- app
        |-- app.component.spec.ts
    |-- mocks
        |-- material
            |-- mat-drawer-container.ts
```

The mock for MaterialDrawerContainer looks like this:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'mat-drawer-container',
   template: ''
})

export class MockMatDrawerContainer {
@Input() mode;
}
```

The test itself still works as expected. But annoyingly, there's a big old red line underneath MockMatDrawerContainer complaining that "MockMatDrawerContainer is not declared in any angular module" even though it is used in the testbed configure test module like so:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule(
            {declarations: [MockMatDrawerContainer]}).compileComponents;
```

I have found the Stack Overflow suggestions for "Compile on changes" and related changes to tsconfig.app.json for compileOnSave, but nothing helps except to create a bogus ngModule in the mock directory, which seems silly.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Preferences* → *Editor* → *Inspections* → *Missing or invalid component, directive, or pipe*.

While the above is technically correct, it still felt hacky as these inspections are put there for a reason.

[A better way to implement a testing library for reuse can be found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-ngrx-store?file=src%2Ftest-helper%2Fmock-store.module.ts).

Answer (score 5):

While you are correct that you should not, as you mention in your answer, disable all inspections of this type for Angular projects, it's definitely a valid use case to disable an inspection for a test mock.

These warnings come from code inspections (both [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) and [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm)).

**To disable any inspection (for any type of project)**:

1. place cursor in the offending code (underlined)
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. select the inspection
4. "Suppress for class"

This will, in this case, add the annotation:

```
// noinspection AngularMissingOrInvalidDeclarationInModule
```

Comment: IDEA is not associated with WebStorm. Do you mean JetBrains? Or [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)?

Comment: Yup typo, fixed 